# Should we migrate existing programming language questions from SO?

Tags: discussion, migration

There are many questions on other stack exchange sites, particularly stack overflow that would be on topic here.

If and when this site leaves beta should some of them be migrated here?

Are there any good reasons for or against this?

Is there precedent for this in other cases? For example when SO spawned programmers, superuser and unix&linux?

This will leads to some related questions like:

- does the existence of this site change the "on topic" rules for SO if those questions were previously on topic?
- which questions (if any) should be migrated?

Just for example SO has the following tags:

- [language-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-design) - 1,354 questions
- [compiler-construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-construction) - 11,581 questions

There is also

- [grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grammar) - 3,232 questions

but I think a smaller subset of those questions are relevant.

Comment: I interpret downvotes as "I disagree with the validity of the question". I think they are being used here to vote for a "no" answer instead. The whole point of raising it is to understand (and possibly discuss) why it might be wrong or right.

Answer (score 4):

Migrations can only happen within 60 days of the question first being posted, and it can only be done if the community of the original host site agrees.

As for un-official migrations, such as copying and pasting a question from elsewhere, or even rewording it, I don't recommend doing that unless it's your own question.

If it's your own question, please also check the original community's policy on cross-site duplicates. Some sites will require you to delete the original post if you post a similar dupe here.

Comment: I didn't know about the 60 day limit.
I was assuming some involvement by the SO team (i.e. the company).